# Update Realm database version

Tags: android, realm

I am using realm, version **0.79.0** in my current android project. Now I want to update realm version to **0.84.0** and also want to use `RealmConfiguration` at Application class to use `Realm.getDefaultInstance()` instead of `Realm.getInstance(context)` for realm initialization.

I implemented new realm version and also change necessary configuration. But when I run my app it crashes with an error says

> Realm Migration must be provided

thought I did not change any model class.

Can anyone please tell me how do I change realm version with default configuration for Android without any migration? If it's not possible without migration then what would the be migration class be like?

Answer (score 2):

You need to migrate because we introduced support for `null` values in 0.83.0. You can read more about how to migrate here: https://realm.io/news/realm-java-0.83.0/

But you need to add a migration that looks something like the below:

```
RealmMigration migration = new RealmMigration() {
    @Override
    public long execute(Realm realm, long version) {
        Table table = realm.getTable(Dog.class);
        // Needed for all Strings
        table.convertColumnToNullable(table.getColumnIndex("name"));
        return 1;
    }
};

RealmConfiguration realmConfig = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(getContext())
    .schemaVersion(1)
    .migration(migration)
    .build();
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you might have skipped many breaking changes. See [changelog](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/master/changelog.txt)

### 0.82

> BREAKING CHANGE: Fields with annotation @PrimaryKey are indexed automatically now. Older schemas require a migration.

Your Migration class should look like this:

```
RealmMigration migration = new RealmMigration() {
   @Override
   public long execute(Realm realm, long version);
      if (version == 1) {
         Table table = realm.getTable(Foo.class);
         long keyIndex = table.getColumnIndex("id");
         table.addSearchIndex(keyIndex);
         version++;
      }
      return version;
   }
};
```

Example from [here](https://realm.io/news/realm-java-0.82.0/)

### 0.83

> BREAKING CHANGE: Introduced boxed types Boolean, Byte, Short, Integer, Long, Float and Double. Added null support. Introduced annotation @Required to indicate a field is not nullable. String, Date and byte[] became nullable by default which means a RealmMigrationNeededException will be thrown if an previous version of a Realm file is opened.

Your Migration class should look like this:

```
RealmMigration migration = new RealmMigration() {
    @Override
    public long execute(Realm realm, long version) {
        Table table = realm.getTable(Dog.class);
        table.convertColumnToNullable(table.getColumnIndex("name"));
        return 1;
    }
};
```

Example from [here](https://realm.io/news/realm-java-0.83.0/)

Answer (score 0):

1) Create a Realm Migration class:
    public class AppRealmMigration implements RealmMigration {

```
@Override
public void migrate(@NonNull final DynamicRealm realm, long oldVersion, long newVersion) {

    // Access the Realm schema in order to create,
    // modify or delete classes and their fields.
    RealmSchema schema = realm.getSchema();
    //region Migrate from version 1 to version 2
    if (oldVersion == 1) {

    //add your code here...

        oldVersion++;
    }

  }
}
```

2) create a custom Application class:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Realm.init(this);


//cation: never changed Realm filename
//changing this default file name create a new database 
//and user after update lose are local data
    RealmConfiguration realmConfig = new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
            .name("your_realm_name")
            .schemaVersion(2)
            .migration(new AppRealmMigration())
            .build();

    Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(realmConfig);
}
}
```

3) Add this class name to your app manifest:

```
<application
   android:name=".MyApplication"
   android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
   android:label="@string/app_name"
   android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
   android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

</application>
```